# How to print framed strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print a frame all arround strings. I want to use ASCII chars from 185 to 188 and from 200 to 206. I want something like this but I don't like the last row because of the wrong allignment on the bottom-right side. It's possible to make it better?

```
retString = "\n╔══> Stanza n. %03d <══╗" % nRoom
retString += "\n╠═> Num letti: %-3d      ║" % nBeds
retString += "\n╠═> Fumatori            ║"
retString += "\n╠═> Televisione         ║"
retString += "\n╠═> Aria Condizionata  ║"
retString += "\n╚══════════════╝"
return retString
```

[image: Output]

Comment: It works for me. Maybe there's something wrong with your Terminal settings? Is this a monospaced font?

Comment: @leovp I have the same problem

Comment: @Christian Cundari What about making the bottom row longer? If you have a variable string length you could make a list of the entries for the frame, pick the longest one and make the bottom row the same length. As for aligning the vertical lines, you could probably do something like `some_entry_in_your_list += (maxlength-len(some_entry_in_your_list))*" " + ||`

Comment: If I run it on terminal it works perfectly. So the problem is with the PyCharm console, but I don't care of it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to draw boxes by hand.
It will break.

I once needed some function to draw boxes, so for documentation reasons I'm posting a cleaned version here:

```
UL, UR = '╔', '╗'
SL, SR = '╠', '║'
DL, DR = '╚', '╝'
AL, AR = '═', '>'


def padded(
    line, info=None, width=42, intro='>', outro='<', filler='.', chopped='..'
):
    # cleanup input
    line = ''.join([' ', line.strip()]) if line else ''
    info = info.strip() if info else ''

    # determine available width
    width -= sum([len(intro), len(outro), len(line), len(info)])
    if width < 0:
        # chop off overflowing text
        line = line[:len(line)+width]
        if chopped:
            # place chopped characters (if set)
            chopped = chopped.strip()
            line = ' '.join([line[:len(line)-(len(chopped)+1)], chopped])

    return ''.join(e for e in [
        intro,
        info,
        line,
        ''.join(filler for _ in range(width)),
        outro
    ] if e)


def box(rnum, nbeds, *extras):
    arrow = (AL+AR)
    res = [
        # head line
        padded(
            'Stanza n. {:03d} <'.format(rnum), (AL+AL+arrow),
            intro=UL, outro=UR, filler=AL
        ),
        # first line
        padded(
            'Num letti: {:3d}'.format(nbeds), arrow,
            intro=SL, outro=SR, filler=' '
        ),
    ]
    # following lines
    res.extend(padded(e, arrow, intro=SL, outro=SR, filler=' ') for e in extras)
    # bottom line
    res.append(padded(None, None, intro=DL, outro=DR, filler=AL))

    return '\n'.join(res)


print(
    box(485, 3, 'Fumatori', 'Televisione')
)
print(
    box(123, 4, 'Fumatori', 'Televisione', 'Aria Condizionata')
)
print(
    box(1, 1, 'this is so much text it will be chopped off')
)
```

The result will look like this:

```
╔═══> Stanza n. 485 <════════════════════╗
╠═> Num letti:   3                       ║
╠═> Fumatori                             ║
╠═> Televisione                          ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╝
╔═══> Stanza n. 123 <════════════════════╗
╠═> Num letti:   4                       ║
╠═> Fumatori                             ║
╠═> Televisione                          ║
╠═> Aria Condizionata                    ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╝
╔═══> Stanza n. 001 <════════════════════╗
╠═> Num letti:   1                       ║
╠═> this is so much text it will be ch ..║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful